# What will be the change in Application behavior after altering table with CODEUNITS32 for supporting unicode behavior?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

we are in a phase of migration of some tables from AS400 DB to DB2 LUW(V11.1). 
While migrating we found some special character(€) in the source database(AS400)- (Column with CHAR) and that lead to error if we are unable to alter table column with CODEUNITS32, DB2 LUW Database configuration Byte Encoding Set at UTF-8.

We want to understand, what would be the behavior of the application after changing the char column to CODEUNITS32, Do I need to update any Configuration at the application level (C & Java Application) to handle both Character Encoding Set?

After changing to CODEUNITS32
- My C application able to compile and able to handle change in Character byte from 8 bit per character(UTF-8) to 4 Byte Per Character(CODEUNITS32)?
- My Java application is able to handle change in Character byte from 8 bit per character(UTF-8) to 4 Byte Per Character(CODEUNITS32)?

We did some pilot testing by inserting Special character manually to the table after setting column definition to CODEUNITS32 from CHAR and testing was successful.

Comment: There are no any problems to use the € character with the (VAR)CHAR(X OCTETS) data types. You should just keep in mind, that you shouldn't use byte-oriented string functions like substr to process such strings. What's the exact command / statement, and what's the exact error message you get working with this character?

Answer (score 1):

Using a string units specification of `CODEUNITS32` for a column does not change the encoding of a column, the data is still stored in UTF-8 for CHAR/VARCHAR columns.

It alters the physical length (`CHAR`) or max length (`VARCHAR`) of the column by a factor of 4.

It also enables "character semantics" in some functions such as `SUBSTR()`, such that they work on characters, not bytes when processing `CODEUNITS32` columns. (`SUBSTRING()` will always use character semantics (unless processing a `FOR BIT DATA` column))

So a `CHAR(4)` is `CHAR(4 OCTETS)` is 4 bytes long, and can hold *at most* 4 characters if they are all single byte in UTF-8. For € which is 3 bytes long, it could only hold say `€4` but not `€42`

A`CHAR(4 CODEUNTIS32)` is 16 bytes long, and is allowed to hold up to 4 characters. It could hold `€€€€` but not `€2345`

It is worth considering avoiding `CHAR(x CODEUNITS32)` and prefering `VARCHAR(x CODEUNITS32)`. `UTF-8` does not really play well with fixed width data types. The more common UTF-8 characters are 1 or 2 bytes long, so typically a `CHAR(x CODEUNITS32)` column will hold be more than 50% space padding.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html

> `CODEUNITS32`
>
> Indicates that the units for the length attribute are Unicode UTF-32 code units which approximate counting in characters.
>
> This unit of length does not affect the underlying code page of the data type.
>
> The actual length of a data value is determined by counting the UTF-32
>   code units as if the data was converted to UTF-32.
>
> A string unit of CODEUNITS32 can be used only in a Unicode database.
>
> CODEUNITS32 can be
>   explicitly specified or determined based on an environment setting.

Also, out of interest, `GRAPHIC`/`VARGRAPHIC` and columns are stored in UTF-16, and default to `CODEUNITS16`, but can also use `CODEUNITS32`.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008471.html

Comment: That's helpful, So do I need to change in the application code(C application/Java) while compiling data for a column of the table where CODEUNITS32 defined?

Comment: I would not have thought so

Comment: @MOHAMMADSHAMSHADHUSSAIN Java code - no. C - depends on how your code is written. But it doesn’t depends on CODEUNITS32. It depends on if your code is suitable for UTF-8.